# How to retrieve location coordinates from Google geocode API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to javascript. I'm trying to retrieve json object from geocoding api and read the latitude and longitude into two variables. Here's what I have done so far. It returns me a wrong json and I'm struggling to process the json.

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

var options = {                 //setting options..host,port,path  etc..
    host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
    path: 'maps/api/geocode/json?address=london+&key=KEY',
    method: 'GET',

var request = http.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(info);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: What JSON is returned? How do you know it's "wrong?"

Comment: @jonmrich I compared it with what returns when I use the same url in browser.